# @Section not rendering in MVC 5 head section

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

Simple question: I want to place some Javascript in my view. I have defined a section in my _Layout:

```
<head>
    @RenderSection("Javascript",required:false)
</head>
```

and on the bottom of my view I have placed:

```
@section Javascript{
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.collapse').on('shown.bs.collapse', function() {
                $(this).parent().find(".glyphicon-plus").removeClass("glyphicon-plus").addClass("glyphicon-minus");
            }).on('hidden.bs.collapse', function() {
                $(this).parent().find(".glyphicon-minus").removeClass("glyphicon-minus").addClass("glyphicon-plus");
            });      
        });
    </script>
}
```

This does not render in my view. What am I missing?

EDIT:

I moved the @RenderSection to the body section of the _Layout page and still did not work. I then took the Javascript and directly injected into the body section of the _Layout and now works? Am I missing another setting for @RenderSection to work?

Comment: See my edit. You might have something else not being right

Comment: Do you have nested layouts?

Comment: @MarkL., And it is a view, an not a partial view?

Comment: Just a normal view....very perplexing

Answer (score 0):

Put `@RenderSection("Javascript",required: false)` right before `</body>` in your `_Layout` file and it should work.

Edit:

Make sure you have a file called `_ViewStart.cshtml` in your `Views` folder that contains

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
```

If you don't. Make sure `Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";` is written in your view file.

Comment: Thanx for answering. I tried this and it is still not rendering.

Comment: I do have  _ViewStart.cshtml in the views folder and it does contain Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";

Comment: Well then try clean your solution rebuild. If it don't work restart Visual Studio.